# Gray highlighted line in file in both editor and minimap?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I see this line highlighted with grey lines in both the minimap and the editor itself. What does that mean / convey?

[image]

Comment: On a command one line above it you missing a dash/minus symbol.

Comment: @bestinamir Not sure I follow. The previous command in my screenshot is `-workbench.action.focusSideBar` (it **has** at minus symbol). Where are you are you saying I'm missing it?

Comment: Just these colorCustomizations: `"editor.lineHighlightBackground"` and   `"editor.lineHighlightBorder"`  Looks like the `editor.lineHighlightBackground`  is set to the editor background itself (or transparent) and the `lineHighlightBorder` is a light gray color.

Comment: All other lines start with -workbench... but the one above starts with workbench...

Comment: Thanks @Mark -- I feel so dumb - of course. I guess I just got confused because I thought I was actually moving the cursor when I scrolled, but I wasn't ... I can accept your comment if you'd like!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those lines are just some combination of these `colorCustomizations`:

`"editor.lineHighlightBackground"` and `"editor.lineHighlightBorder"`

Looks like the `editor.lineHighlightBackground` is set to the editor background itself (or transparent) and the `lineHighlightBorder` is a light gray color.